# File asset fingerprint is not updating correctly on Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, fingerprint

In my rails 3.1 app, while deploying, the assets is compiled and gets uploaded successfully.

When I visit the app, the css and js files are referenced but the server give back 404.

```
<link href="/assets/application-f997bad128b3d8a92ed5619470851dab.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/application-d7eac22b3bc8b4e3620abb21f59a5faa.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Looking on the server, the fingerprint that is printed on the html markup doesn't match so the server returns 404.

But I wonder how the hell this happens.

So, what are the factors that change the fingerprinting of the manifest files?

Comment: Is manifest.yml gettin uploaded as well as the assets (or are you doing the precompilation on the server)

Comment: Yes, I checked it again to confirm, its getting uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your server wasn't reloaded. I've experienced this issue when Unicorn didn't switch over after sending the `USR2` signal to the process. I had to manually kill and restart the process to get it going again.